# Cassandra Cluster Recovery

Tags: cassandra, spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I have a Spring Boot Application that uses Spring Data for Cassandra. One of the requirements is that the application will start even if the Cassandra Cluster is unavailable. The Application logs the situation and all its endpoints will not work properly but the Application does not shutdown. It should retry to connect to the cluster during this time. When the cluster is available the application should start to operate normally. 
If I am able to connect during the application start and the cluster becomes unavailable after that, the cassandra java driver is capable of managing the retries.
How can I manage the retries during application start and still use Cassandra Repositories from Spring Data?

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to start a Spring Boot application if Apache Cassandra is not available but you need to define the `Session` and `CassandraTemplate` beans on your own with `@Lazy`. The beans are provided out of the box with `CassandraAutoConfiguration` but are initialized eagerly (default behavior) which creates a `Session`. The `Session` requires a connection to Cassandra which will prevent a startup if it's not initialized lazily.

The following code will initialize the resources lazily:

```
@Configuration
public class MyCassandraConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public CassandraTemplate cassandraTemplate(@Lazy Session session, CassandraConverter converter) throws Exception {
        return new CassandraTemplate(session, converter);
    }

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public Session session(CassandraConverter converter, Cluster cluster,
            CassandraProperties cassandraProperties) throws Exception {
        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setCluster(cluster);
        session.setConverter(converter);
        session.setKeyspaceName(cassandraProperties.getKeyspaceName());
        session.setSchemaAction(SchemaAction.NONE);
        return session.getObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> One of the requirements is that the application will start even if the Cassandra Cluster is unavailable

I think you should read this session from the Java driver doc: http://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/#cluster-initialization

The `Cluster` object does not connect automatically unless some calls are executed.

Since you're using Spring Data Cassandra (that I do not recommend since it has less feature than the plain Mapper Module of the Java driver ...) I don't know if the `Cluster` object or `Session` object are exposed directly to the users ...

For retry, you can put the `cluster.init()` call in a try/catch block and if the cluster is still unavaible, you'll catch an `NoHostAvailableException` according to the docs. Upon the exception, you can schedule a retry of  `cluster.init()`  later